# TinyIoC property injection with BuildUp not working in Xamarin.iOS app

Tags: c#, ios, dependency-injection, xamarin, tinyioc

I'm having a little trouble figuring out why I can't do property injection in a ViewController in a Xamarin iOS app.

My types are registered and they resolve correctly in my ViewController constructor by using this code:

```
myService = TinyIoCContainer.Current.Resolve<IMyService>();
```

But instead of assigning all deps manually, I believe I should be able to have TinyIoC "fill up" my ViewController's public properties by using:

```
TinyIoCContainer.Current.BuildUp (this);
```

in the constructor of my ViewController, but as soon as I try to run this line of code, even without any public properties specified on my ViewController - I get a stackoverflow exception and a whole lot of errors following that.

Can anyone tell me what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: Show the exact exception.

Comment: The exception is a System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException.

I've tried debugging a bit and have come to the conclusion that it seems like TinyIoC is trying to inject some properties that are inherited from UIViewController class.

By adding a [Inject] attribute to the specific properties I would like to have it handle, and then modifying TinyIoC to only inject to properties with this attribute, I actually have a working BuildUp() method now - which also supports my suspicion on TinyIoC failing on some attributes from the UIViewController class.

Comment: However, if anyone know if this can be solved somehow other than by this method, I would be very pleased!